# Expose Kubernetes Dashboard to outside using Ingress return 404

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to expose the dashboard to outside using Ingress. Below is my ingress configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
   rules:
     - http:
          paths:
            - path: /dashboard
              backend:
                serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
                servicePort: 80
```

And the `kubernetes-dashboard` service:

```
kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.98.198.125   <none>        80/TCP    10d
```

Then when I access the outside, I got `404 page not found`. What did I do wrong in the configuration?

Comment: Hi,  the port number and service name are correct ?

Comment: Hi yes, they are correct. Above I just updated the description

Comment: Hi, do you have an ingress controller and a default backend installed on your cluster?

Comment: Hi smace, I think I did not have them installed on the cluster. I thought the dashboard is a built in service  and here I just need to expose it using Ingress, so I just defined here an Ingress for it. Could you please give me some hints how these extra things need to be installed then?

Answer (score 1):

So I have investigated this, and it is a little bit tricky case.

I installed nginx with Helm Chart.

So first of all, my Ingress.yaml worked with only this two annotations:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`
```

After that you will meet a new problem, which is dashboard will not work on /dashboard or any other path. It only works with path `/` even tho curl shows 200 and all seems to be fine - page still stays as blank.

Unfortunately I could not find a solution to that although I tried multiple configurations and workarounds. You can read more about it in this [GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/683) issue where there is a workaround - but unfortunately it did not work for me as well.

Hope I spared you some time on thinking why /dashboard does not work, even after the config is correct :)